# SVN Symfony Best Practice

Tags: svn, symfony1

So I am starting a Symfony project that I will be developing on my local machine and pushing changes everyday to the live server. I wanna use SVN as the version control but Im not sure what the best way to set it up is.

Do i make the actual html directory on the server be the repo so that when I check things in it goes live? Do I make it a separate directory and move things over by hand?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, SVN is absolutely fine to use as version control - use it for your Symfony project in the same way you would any other project.  The one thing to remember is that you shouldn't check out your project on your live/production server as you will end up with .svn directories visible to the outside world.  Information about putting your Symfony project into a local Subversion server is available [in the Symfony docs](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/01).

To combat the problem of having .svn directories on your live server, use Symfony's `project:deploy` command, detailed [in the Symfony docs](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/22).  This should be run from a clean checkout, eg on a deployment server, or somewhere else locally.  The deploy command will copy the necessary files to the live server of your choice, excluding any version control files etc.  This ensures that only what is needed is on your live server.

Comment: I agree, it's also wise to have your web server deny access to any file with the pattern .* so .htaccess, .svn, .project, etc don't  "accidentally" leak

Answer (score 0):

Check the first chapter of the `Jobeet` tutorial. There is a whole section about `Subversion`.

[Day 1: Starting up the Project](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/01)